# Vue Use function for module configuration without createApp() function? Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, web3js, nuxt3, wagmi

In the following code, is there a Vue function that I can use to get the same effect as `app.use(UseWagmiPlugin, config);` without importing `'./app.vue` and using `createApp()`?
(Link to github docs here: https://github.com/unicape/use-wagmi#documentation)

```
import { UseWagmiPlugin, createConfig, sepolia } from 'use-wagmi'
import { createPublicClient, http } from 'viem'
import App from './app.vue'

const config = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  publicClient: createPublicClient({
    chain: sepolia,
    transport: http(),
  }),
})

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(UseWagmiPlugin, config);
app.mount('#app');
```

I know nuxt3 doesn't need routing like this (the `'use-wagmi'` .readme seems to be for a straight `vue.js` app) and as far as I can see there isn't a glaringly obvious reason that I should need to and that the `use-wagmi` module shouldn't be working but it doesn't, the error message says that I have to use `useConfig` with `UseWagmiPlugin`. And using just import statements for `'wagmi'` breaks my Nuxt app.

I have roamed around all the best forums and discords and I can't find anyone who's posted a good answer for this situation. Straight `ethers.js` has not been successful with vue either and I think this is a ssr/client/websocket issue, 'wagmi' is react based and the 'use-wagmi' module is a roll out specifically for nuxt so I feel like I'm missing something seemingly simple. Any suggestions for any of these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what is your case? It's unclear how is Nuxt related to this. Are you trying to use vanilla vue plugin in Nuxt app?

Comment: I'm not using it as a plugin at the moment I am treating it as a module. If you check out the documentation in the link at the top of my post it might give you a better idea. I'm just trying to use the module ```use-wagmi``` functions... at all, but when I add them to the script tag of a page, the app will no longer load and gives me the 'UseWagmiPlugin' with 'useConfig' error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A vue composable presumes that there can be another part that needs initial setup. In case this part exists, this should be done with a plugin. This is the case. Most likely you can't omit it without breaking a composable, this has to determined by trial and error.

Comment: ```export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@vueuse/nuxt',
    '@use-wagmi/nuxt'
  ],}```  It's not a vanilla vue plugin if I'm adding it to the modules in nuxt config right?

Comment: Nuxt plugin generally is expected to do the same thing as vanilla vue one but with some nuxt specific things in mind. In this case you can check usewagmi/nuxt implementation to confirm that it's incomplete, this still requires a vue plugin to be installed to nuxt app. This is what the example shows https://github.com/unicape/use-wagmi/blob/main/examples/nuxt/plugins/use-wagmi.ts . This looks like the case of incomplete documentation. In case this was your problem, that's it

Comment: This does seem to be the answer. I have some more script to write before I can confirm but thank you. I should have dove into the examples further. Thank you for your help! I guess sometimes we just need another pair of eyes.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: I don't know if you want to edit this and post the comment with the link as the answer but it was the correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuxt plugins are generally expected to do the same thing as regular Vue plugins but with some Nuxt-specific functionality. But it can be seen in the [example](https://github.com/unicape/use-wagmi/blob/main/examples/nuxt/plugins/use-wagmi.ts) that custom Nuxt plugin also needs to be used to install the plugin to Vue instance in addition to `@use-wagmi/nuxt` plugin:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  ...
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(UseWagmiPlugin, config)
})
```